# Can I get my React component to render conditionally with renderToStaticMarkup?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of components that I'm preparing for automated visual regression testing (VRT) and have a system set up to do that rendering them individually with `ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup` for the tests to reference.

On the visual side, theses components are sometimes wrapped in a `WrapperComponent` with extra styles to display them differently when viewed on screen for human eyes.

Is there a way to make the `WrapperComponent` aware of its renderer (so to speak), so that I can conditionally omit the `WrapperComponent` from the markup that's sent to VRT?

Essentially I'd to do something like:

```
ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(componentPossiblyWithWrapperComponentInside)
```

In the `WrapperComponent`:

```
class WrapperComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return isBeingRenderedForVRT ?
      this.props.children :
      (
      <div className='wrapper-component-for-human-screens'>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the point in visual regression testing if what you're testing isn't what actually gets shown to the users?

Comment: In short, the unwrapped markup rendered from the component is the product that is ultimately consumed by the user. The Wrapper is for showcasing.

Comment: What exactly does "showcasing" mean? What part of the visuals are *not* "for human eyes"?